# Getting traceback on pymysql with script

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Got a simple script that is given below. When trying to run the script, I get traceback error that I cannot quite figure out. The error and script are below. I am running python 3.4 as is required. Not sure what is going on exactly. Any help is appreciated. It says its a syntax error on import... yet its the only import.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 1, in 
import pymysql
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql_*init*_.py", line 59, in 
from . import connections  # noqa: E402
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 206
):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import pymysql  
myConnection  = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user = 'root', password='******', database='accidents')  

cur = myConnection.cursor()  

cur.execute('SELECT vtype FROM vehicle_type WHERE  vtype LIKE "%otorcycle%";')  

cycleList = cur.fetchall()  

selectSQL = ('''                 
 SELECT  t.vtype, a.accident_severity                  
 FROM accidents_2016 AS a                  
 JOIN vehicles_2016 AS v ON  a.accident_index = v.Accident_Index                  
 JOIN vehicle_type AS t ON  v.Vehicle_Type = t.vcode                  
 WHERE t.vtype LIKE %s                  
 ORDER BY  a.accident_severity;
 ''')  

insertSQL = ('''
    INSERT INTO accident_medians  VALUES (%s, %s);
    ''')    

for cycle  in cycleList:                  
    cur.execute(selectSQL,cycle[0])                  
    accidents = cur.fetchall()                  
    quotient, remainder =  divmod(len(accidents),2)                  
    if  remainder:                                  
        med_sev =  accidents[quotient][1]                  
    else:                                  
        med_sev =  (accidents[quotient][1] + accidents[quotient+2][1])/2                  

print('Finding median  for',cycle[0])                  

cur.execute(insertSQL,(cycle[0],med_sev))  
myConnection.commit()  
myConnection.close()
```

This is from connections.py. Which seems to be the standard install file.

```
def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        user=None,  # The first four arguments is based on DB-API 2.0 recommendation.
        password="",
        host=None,
        database=None,
        unix_socket=None,
        port=0,
        charset="",
        sql_mode=None,
        read_default_file=None,
        conv=None,
        use_unicode=True,
        client_flag=0,
        cursorclass=Cursor,
        init_command=None,
        connect_timeout=10,
        read_default_group=None,
        autocommit=False,
        local_infile=False,
        max_allowed_packet=16 * 1024 * 1024,
        defer_connect=False,
        auth_plugin_map=None,
        read_timeout=None,
        write_timeout=None,
        bind_address=None,
        binary_prefix=False,
        program_name=None,
        server_public_key=None,
        ssl=None,
        ssl_ca=None,
        ssl_cert=None,
        ssl_disabled=None,
        ssl_key=None,
        ssl_verify_cert=None,
        ssl_verify_identity=None,
        compress=None,  # not supported
        named_pipe=None,  # not supported
        passwd=None,  # deprecated
        db=None,  # deprecated
    ):  -- line 206
```

Comment: can you open the file `C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py` and post the line 206 here?

Comment: I added it to the main post above. It ends with ' ): '
I tagged it with -- line 206

Comment: does it say anything more,after the invalid syntax? I can run that def init without problem on python 3.9.2. without any syntax error

Comment: negative. what I posted was the entire traceback.

Comment: would you try running it with a newer python?

Comment: will that override what I already have? version 3.4 is required for my classes.

Comment: You can run multiple versions on windows, however to be sure backup you project. This is how to setup multiple versions: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-install-and-manage-multiple-python-versions-on-windows-10-c90098d7ba5a

Comment: so why do you nbeed the connection.py when you don't use it and when you want tio use it, you need to inpout all need informastioon like port 33ß6 and so on

Comment: Ok. So I installed a newer version of python3.9.2 and installed pymysql onto that and it worked just fine, with a few minor tweaks to the script I wrote above that I overlooked to the get the proper results. The result is fine. So I'm assuming its a version issue or a problem with the install of 3.4. 

However, I did uninstall 3.4 and reinstall it a few different times just to make sure. So it could be simply a version issue I would think. Not too sure. But it works. 

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when running a script using python 3.5.2. I followed the suggestion here https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/issues/282#issuecomment-776937071 and downgraded my pymysql, which solved the problem

```
pip uninstall pymysql
pip install -Iv pymysql==0.9.3
```